# HTML renders differently in ColdFusion 9

Tags: iis-7, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have a really strange issue. I just moved my ColdFusion application from ColdFusion 8/IIS 6 to ColdFusion 9/IIS 7.

None of the HTML files were modified; just copied and pasted to the new server's web root. But the pages are rendering slightly differently. It's as if the CSS margin settings and padding settings for the layout are not being applied in the same way. The elements are bunching together whereas there was proper spacing before I moved the application over.

I thought ColdFusion server wouldn't interfere with any formatting of HTML pages as it just handles back-end requests, but these pages clearly look different on the older version of ColdFusion/IIS.

Is there anything that would make this happen in ColdFusion or IIS? I'm just using CFM pages with basic CSS styling, etc. Nothing crazy.

Comment: to be honest, it sounds like you might have missed copying a CSS file across.  Setup a test page with no CSS and then apply CSS and see if it matches the output render you expect.

Comment: Have you actually *compared* the resultant mark-up to ensure it actually *is* the same? CF doesn't have a hand in rendering anything, so they "only" way it can be different is if different content is being sent to the browser.

Comment: I've actually narrowed it down to a table that all of my elements are in. <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="5"> If I change the padding to 100, it has no effect in Chrome but DOES in Firefox. This is only happened since moving my files to a Windows 2008 server/IIS7/Coldfusion9.

Comment: Again... none of "Windows 2008 server/IIS7/Coldfusion9" have any bearing on how the browser renders mark-up. You need to check what you're sending to the browser, and work out what's different about it; then work out what caused the difference, and fix the difference.

Comment: same browser versions as before?  i'm with @AdamCameron on this, these server side tech won't render it differently,

Comment: Yes, browser version are the same. If I create a CSS class with the table settings that I would like to appear, it works. But I would rather find out what is preventing the table tags from rendering properly than go through all the code modifying it. How do I go about doing "check what you're sending to the browser, and work out what's different about it;"?

Comment: To check what you are sending to the browser, view the html source code.  The way to do that depends on the browser, but right clicking on the web page is usually a good start.

Comment: @user234215 `view source` in the browser and save it. Do for both installs. Then use a diffing tool to compare. Do same with asset files such as CSS and JS which contribute to the rendering of the mark-up.

Answer (score 2):

I'll brave an answer. Here are some things to try (or at least think about):

I am assuming that there are no errors and that just the HTML is wacky (but workable).

In your CF Admin head over to 'Settings':

Look for 'Enable Whitespace Management': (which described) Reduces the file size of the pages that ColdFusion returns to the browser by removing many of the extra spaces, tabs, and carriage returns that ColdFusion might otherwise persist from the CFML source file.

See if it is checked if not check it and see if you notice any changes expected or unexpected.

And look for `<cfsetting>` tags with the `enablecfoutputonly` set to `no/yes` or `true/false` or `0/1` (or lack of the parameter)

Next is: `<cfprocessingdirective>`

Look for page that does this:

```
<cfprocessingdirective
pageEncoding = "page-encoding literal string"
suppressWhiteSpace = "yes|no">
</cfprocessingdirective
```

`pageEncoding = "page-encoding literal string"` <<< this could do some things to on a character level that you might consider.

[See Adam's colorful post here for encoding details.](http://cfmlblog.adamcameron.me/2012/10/why-just-why.html)

Provides the following information to ColdFusion about how to process the current page:

Specifies whether to remove excess whitespace character from ColdFusion generated content in the tag body.
Identifies the character encoding (character set) of the page contents.

Also check for these `<cfcontent>` and `<cfsilent>`

Maybe that will unravel some mysteries for you (Or make more depending what you find when you run some searches through your code)...

On a last note.  I am not sure what your code base contains, but if you run into some things you can consolidate consider using the `Application.cfc` then move all these white space encoding things here.  Somethings do similar things to others so you might want to clip the redundancy to a single point of failure that way you don't have individual pages replicating actions when they don't need to.

Oh, one last thing, make sure you turn your caching off because some of this sounds like someone trying to beat overhead on pages.  If you have caching on and render pages while you are making changes you may not see your fixes and then you will pull your hair out.  We don't want that.

:)

Good luck.

Comment: The question talks about html files.  They won't have any coldfusion tags.

Comment: @DanBracuk I used to make HTML files as a caching mechanism with Coldfusion, I would check to see if the HTML page existed, or not, then render the page while at the same time making the HTML cache file so it would be checked on the next go around. But who knows.  maybe these are static HTML pages that never change.  I have one or two of these on my sites.  But that's not how I interpreted things so you might be right.